# Is it "more just" or "juster"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, comparatives

I was recently writing a sentence and added the words "more just", only for my extension Grammarly to flag the phrase and suggest "juster" instead. Is "juster" really a comparative form of "just"? If so, is it proper grammar to use "juster" instead of "more just". And just for my sanity, if "juster" is the correct form to use, am I the only one who thinks it sounds really weird? Whatever knowledge you have is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is, in my humble opinion, another case of "more 90 degrees". So yeah, both sound weird, but one sounds more weird.

Comment: I would say that "juster" is a hair less formal than "more just" -- the latter sounds more suited to use in a court of law, eg.  But both are "correct".

Answer (score 6):

While the comparative *juster* does not appear in the works of Shakespeare, the Bard does use the superlative in *Antony and Cleopatra*:

> Pompey. If the great gods be just, they shall assist
>   The deeds of [*justest*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=justest;id=njp.32101063693137;view=image;seq=40;start=1;sz=10;page=root;num=32;size=100;orient=0) men. — A&C 2.1

The Early English Books Online corpus does show, however,  that both *juster* and *more just* were current in other writers of Early Modern English:

> …and no man of evill, but the lord did convay goodnes into him at some time, to make his condemnation the *juster*: — Richard Greenham, *Propositions containing answers to certaine demaunds in divers spirituall matters*, 1597. EEBO
>
> …if there were any divine providence, seing that he who had the *more just cause*, was so over-come: — Robert Pont, *A newe treatise of the right reckoning of yeares*, 1599. EEBO

Even so, *more just* occurs far more frequently in the EEBO corpus with 1265 attestations to 679 for *juster*.  Both forms continue in use until the early 20th c., but by mid-century, search results show far more occurences of the surname Juster than anything resembling the comparative adjective.

> Even though no other advantage were to be obtained from our present [*juster*](https://books.google.de/books?id=eHxZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA10&dq=%22juster%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5hY_8kI7hAhWHMewKHaFwDKkQ6AEISDAH) views of mind, … — Thomas Brown, *Philososophy of the Human Mind*, 1860, 10.
>
> The whole brotherhood will live and let live, making [*juster*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=juster;id=mdp.39015070266120;view=image;seq=13;start=1;sz=10;page=root;num=7;size=100;orient=0) laws. — William Mercer Grosvenor, *The Puritan Remnant*, 1911.
>
> It was this hope and this implicit trust in a saner and [*juster*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22juster%20world%22;id=mdp.39015001343162;view=image;seq=228;num=644;start=1;sz=10;page=root;size=100;orient=0) world order which acted as a moderating influence on the forces of revolution and eventually determined the triumph of constitutional government over leftist radicalism. — Kurt F. Reinhardt, *Germany: 2000 Years*, vol.2, 1962, 644.

A  book of essays in English, [*For a Better and Juster World*](https://books.google.de/books?id=pOMMAAAAYAAJ&q=%22juster%22&dq=%22juster%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj30ZPvwo7hAhUGGewKHUNtABoQ6AEILDAB) was published in communist Romania in 1975, but the volume was not edited by a native speaker.

The only reason I can think of why Grammarly would suggest *juster* is that its algorithm is merely following the rule of comparing single-syllable adjectives with *-er, -est* and not tweaking the rule to reflect actual usage.

Comment: So would you say that Earl Warren was the justest justice?

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that '*juster*' and '*justest*' should sound wrong. 'Just' is a monosyllabic adjective and [the rules for making comparative and superlative forms are simple](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives/). Perhaps they sound odd because 'just' is, er, just so familiar in its [other meanings](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/just)...?

On reflection, 'more just' sounds like a childish mistake like, say, 'more hot'.

> A simple maid, With justest grief and wrong so ill apaid. P. Fletcher Purple Island xi. xii. 148 (1633) (OED)
>
> A single glance of a good plate or a picture imprints a juster idea than a volume could convey. O. Goldsmith Hist. Earth V. 136 (1774) (OED)

Answer (score 0):

I perused some google results for "juster or more just", only reading on the results page itself, and apparently juster is acceptable. But I am certain I have heard "more just" far more often.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why Grammarly would prompt you to use "juster" rather than "more just" is because writing "more just" is like writing "more hot" - a mistake.

But because "more just" is commonly used than "juster" out of ignorance, this mistake had become more widespread and "acceptable".

Like finding out about the correct pronunciations of words, they always sound "mispronounced" and weird at first.

Had users of "more just" known that the word "juster" exists in the English language, as even Shakespeare had used the superlative "justest", they would have used it, as people generally favour a shorter word to say or write something quicker. Wouldn't you, if you had known this? Why do you think I'm on this StackExchange page, if I did not hear a narrator on a Whatsapp video saying "juster"?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, Richard Tan. The perspective you offer is interesting, but it doesn't accord with the proportions of usage reported by Early English Books Online. EEBO finds [1,263 instances of "juster" across 998 different books](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?sort=datea&ALLSELECTED=1&xc=1&g=eebogroup&type=simple&rgn=full+text&q1=juster&singlegenre=All&c=eebo&c=eebo2&view=reslist&subview=short&start=1&size=25) from the years 1509–1700. ...

Comment: ... It also finds [2,495 instances of "more just" across 1,747 different books](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?ALLSELECTED=1&xc=1&g=eebogroup&type=simple&rgn=full+text&q1=more+just&cite1=&cite1restrict=author&cite2=&cite2restrict=author&singlegenre=All&Submit=Search&c=eebo&c=eebo2) for the period 1553–1700. ...

Comment: ... Interestingly, six of the instances of "juster" appear as part of the longer wording ["more juster"](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?sort=datea&ALLSELECTED=1&xc=1&g=eebogroup&type=simple&rgn=full+text&q1=more+juster&singlegenre=All&c=eebo&c=eebo2&view=reslist&subview=short&start=1&size=25) from works published in 1509, 1636, 1649, 1652, 1661, and 1699. ...

Comment: ... If you remove the "more juster" instance from the year 1509 from consideration, the earliest EEBO instance of "juster" to mean "more just" is from 1597—forty-four years after the first instance of "more just" (1553). In any event, for the two centuries (1501–1700) that EEBO tracks, "more just" is nearly twice as common as "juster": 2,495 to 1,263 in individual instances, and 1,747 to 998 in different books. So if, today, "juster" is the only correct form of the comparative and "more just" is a mistake, that rule evidently arose at some point after 1700.